# Function doesn't Break

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, recursion

I am trying to break out or restart a function in python 2. Putting a return statement should stop all execution. Same goes for restarting the function.

```
def function():
    ...
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return value
        print 'foo'
    else:
        function()
        print 'foo'
```

In this case 'foo' would be printed twice.

Comment: The first `print 'foo'` is unreachable, but the second isn't: it will be called after the recursive invocation of `function` returns. It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking, but I suspect that you want a simple loop that calls your `function` rather than making `function` recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement only stops the execution of the **current** instance of the function.

Since you're doing a recursion, you will still get the other calls of that function running until they hit their own `return` (if any).